# Postfix mail for mydomain.com loops back to myself

Tags: postfix

I'm using vps server with ubuntu 10.04 when i send email i got this:

```
Mar 19 18:09:01 mail postfix/smtp[6340]: 8FAF722294: to=<root@mydomain.com>, orig_to=<root>, relay=none, delay=0.09, delays=0.08/0.01/0/0, dsn=5.4.6, status=bounced (mail for mydomain.com loops back to myself)
```

I look around inforums to find the solution but in vain even i changed my Postfix settings:

My destination setting was like this

```
mail.mydomain.com, localhost.mydomain.com, , localhost
```

i changed it to this

```
$mail.mydomain.com, localhost, localhost.mydomain.com, mydomain.com
```

i made many variations but still not working.

the output of `cat /etc/mailname`

```
mail.mydomain.com
```

the output of `postconf -n`:

```
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
append_dot_mydomain = no
biff = no
config_directory = /etc/postfix
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = ipv4
mailbox_size_limit = 0
milter_default_action = accept
milter_protocol = 2
mydestination = localhost.$mydomain.com, localhost, mail.mydomain.com
myhostname = mail.dimonos.info
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128 ip
myorigin = $mydomain
non_smtpd_milters = inet:localhost:8891
readme_directory = no
recipient_delimiter = +
relayhost =
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
smtpd_milters = inet:localhost:8891
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtpd_use_tls = yes
```

Comment: Do you want the mail to be delivered locally or externally?

Comment: locally i use my own smtp to send an email.

Answer (score 4):

Based on comments:

The problem is the sending of a mail to *hotmail.com*, thus the problem is unlikely to be linked to *mydestination*, and it appears DNS resolution is not setup.

In this case please put a value in `/etc/resolv.conf` either based from your ISP data (DNS servers), or use the *Google* server - eg for Google:

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
```

then try to resolve the MX entries for *hotmail.com*

```
host -t mx hotmail.com
```

If that works, you can now try to send an email to *hotmail.com*

Note: if you use the NetworkManager, use it instead to set the DNS servers values.

Note2: if that doesn't work, please display the last lines of `/var/log/mail.log`

-- *edit - previous answer for a local delivery problem* --

The `$mydomain` variable ([some info](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#mydomain)) is set to the local machine name minus the first component (`/etc/mailname` is used on Debian). When you send a mail to *root@mydomain.com* a MX DNS query is performed to identify what server is expected to accept the mail. The first step is to check what is that server

```
host -t mx mydomain.com
```

that will give you what you have to add to *mydestination* for postfix to understand the mail is to be delivered locally,

```
mydestination = localhost.$mydomain, localhost, mail.$mydomain
```

If the result is actually your domain (you can check the name with

```
hostname
uname -n
```

if you get a FQDN entity, remove the first component - e.g. for `home.mydomain.com`, your *domain* as set by posftix is *domain.com*. And ensure that value is in *mydestination* (if the value from `host` it is the same as $mydomain, simply set

```
mydestination = localhost.$mydomain, localhost, mail.$mydomain, $mydomain
```

Comment: when i check `host -t mx mydomain.com` it tells `host: parse of /etc/resolv.conf failed` and when i check my hotname is mail.mydomain.info

Comment: That means your system cannot send mail outside since DNS resolution is not setup - this is not the problem anyway. Add $mydomain to *mydestination* and mail should be delivered locally (or simply  add 'mydomain.info', the mail should go to 'root@mydomain.info')

Comment: i have already send an email Gmail and works fine. the loop back to myself appair when i try to send to hotmail.

Comment: Ah, this is the opposite problem! Let me edit the answer...

Comment: In this case, what can i do ?

Comment: Did you read my edited answer?

Comment: i use this command `host -t mx hotmail.com` it tells `host: parse of /etc/resolv.conf failed`. when i add mx records to hotmail what can i add exactly in MX server?

Comment: .. and which value i will add in `/etc/resolv.conf`, i already found my server ip.

Comment: Your system needs to be able to resolve DNS names to send mail to hotmail. See [this](http://theos.in/desktop-linux/resolve-conf-linux-example/) for instance, or [that](http://askubuntu.com/questions/157154/how-do-i-add-changes-to-resolv-conf-without-them-getting-overwritten-on-reboot)

Comment: I'm little confused, when i open resolv.config with nano i have to add nameserver of hotmail?

Comment: Copy the 2 lines from my answer: nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4

Comment: ok and how can i resolve the MX entries for hotmail in dns manager?